# Flask mail or Marrow mailer

Tags: python, flask, mailer, flask-mail

I am working on a flask project. Large part of the project has already been implemented by some previous developers. Going through the code I saw previous developers have implemented 
[Marrow Mailer](https://github.com/marrow/marrow.mailer)
. So I am just curious what is the reason for having this preference over [Flask Mail](https://pythonhosted.org/flask-mail/)

Answer (score 2):

From a features perspective, Marrow Mail offers asynchronous mail delivery. This allows for processing of e-mails outside of the request lifecycle, which, for example, means your visitors can be sent the "Thank you for signing up!" page before the SMTP connection even gets initiated to send them a welcome e-mail.

Comment: Ok but now I have added celery to the project. So wouldn't it be better to use flask mail with celery for asynchronous emails?